# How to enable button after at least one row has been checked in Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

In this test code, I have a button that I want to be disabled if no checkboxes are checked and enabled if at least one checkbox is checked.

The function to do this works but not on data tables. I am trying to make it work on datatables. But its not working with me

This is not my code... This is just to test.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets: 0
      },
      {
        "visible": false,
        "searchable": false,
      }
    ],
    select: {
      style: 'multi',
      selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    order: [
      [1, 'asc']
    ]
  })

  var checkBoxes = $('.select-checkbox');
  checkBoxes.change(function() {
    $('#btnSelectedRows').prop('disabled', checkBoxes.filter(':checked').length < 1);
  });
  $('.select-checkbox').change();

});


<
/script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
  <link href='http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/build/toastr.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.22/datatables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>


  <button id="btnSelectedRows" name="btnSelectedRows" data-target="#grnModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-s">
                click
                </button>
  <table class="dataTable" id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Rendering engine</th>
        <th>Browser</th>
        <th>Platform(s)</th>
        <th>Engine version</th>
        <th>CSS grade</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


      <tr>

        <td></td>
        <td>Misc</td>
        <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
        <td>Embedded devices</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>X</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Misc</td>
        <td>Links</td>
        <td>Text only</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>X</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Misc</td>
        <td>Lynx</td>
        <td>Text only</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>X</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Misc</td>
        <td>IE Mobile</td>
        <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Misc</td>
        <td>PSP browser</td>
        <td>PSP</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Other browsers</td>
        <td>All others</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>U</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a delegated event listener to the table, listen for change and check if any checkbox is checked

```js
var table = $("#example");
var btn = $('#btnSelectedRows');

function enableBtn() {
  btn.prop("disabled", table.find("input:checked").length === 0)
}

table.on("change", "input", enableBtn);
enableBtn();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btnSelectedRows">Test</button>

<table id="example">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

DataTables also have selection event

```
table.on( 'deselect', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) { console.log(indexes);});
table.on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {console.log(indexes);});
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this code. It does the same thing as my code... it disables but doesn't enable when boxes are checked

Comment: Swap it to click instead of change

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I used the DataTables selection events and it worked! :D

Answer (score -1):

in document ready load datatable without putting any condition and after datatable you can put these lines of code

```
if($(document).find("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked').length === 0)
{
  $('#btn').prop("disabled", true);
}
```

Comment: thank you, I tried this but it didn't work for my case.